# Authorize.net: Using PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE need update the Invoice number

Tags: authorize.net

We are using AIM module for our website. In first call we are using **AUTH_ONLY**. If everything is okay then we are using **PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE** to capture the amount. The Problem here is we need to update the Invoice number in the second call (**PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE**). How can we achieve this ? because "**priorAuthCapture**" method accepts only `transaction id` and `amount` as parameters.

Is there any other function is there in Authorize.net AIM to update the Invoice number after the payments successful ?

> $transaction->invoice_num = $generatedInvoiceID;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality does not exist. The `AUTH_ONLY` essentially *is* the transaction. The `PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE` just completes it by officially stating you wish to capture those funds. But the details already presented during the `AUTH_ONLY` cannot be changed.

Comment: Yes. I agree now :) @john

Answer (score 0):

In Cybersource if you enter a default value of 0 with prior auth capture, it will capture the original amount of the transaction. Change 0 to the actual dollar amount if you want to capture less than the original amount. If you wish to capture more than the original amount you will need to complete a new authorization or new authorization and capture.